# Django rest. image url sends to html page but not to the image location

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Have a picture upload in django rest app. The url is created and looks fine 
[image]

image related code is:

**Setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = "uploads"
```

**URL**

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

when click on the url the web browser shows nothing- just white(instead of picture). Inspected the page. It sends me not to the image but to the index.html file where I mounted my app:

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Combinator optimizer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

{% render_bundle 'app' %}

Answer (score 0):

In my main url to the index view

```
re_path(r"^.*", IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name='index.html')
```

replace

```
 "^.*"   for '^$'
```